# Why Format String Attack occurs in C?

Tags: c, printf, buffer-overflow, format-string

I know that Format String Attack occurs when a formatted I/O function expects more arguments than the provided ones.

In C,

one example for reading a memory location:

```
printf("%x"); // this prints a memory address location in the stack
```

Another example for overwriting a memory location:

```
printf("Overwritten%n"); //this prints the number of chars in "Overwritten"
```

My questions is: Why does this happen in both cases? Why having only %x in the formatted string without providing a corresponding value would print me an address in the memory? And what's that address exactly? I know it happens, but what's really going on?

Same for overwriting.

Comment: I suggest reading about calling conventions: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention

Comment: Follow links from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string), search the terms used there. There are even videos about this on youtube.

Answer (score 4):

What occurs is undefined behavior. Printf don't know that there is no corresponding value. It tries to access the 2nd parameter of your call (which you did not provide), and access some random memory value.

For the `"overwritten%n"`, %n stores in the memory the number of characters written until you call %n. If you call if without passing a correct adress, it will write something in a random place, risking to corrupt your memory.

Answer (score 2):

Given that C is named "high-level assembler", the answer lies in its compiler structure. `printf` is a function, that accepts variable number of arguments without ever checking whether all of them were actually supplied. So, depending on how is that function accepts arguments at compiler level, the following scenario is possible:

First, the string that's passed to printf is parsed, resulting in a subsequent call of an inner function, that would output a string 'Overwritten' in the second case (in the first case the very first symbol of formatted string is a '%' which signifies a parameter). Then, when a parameter is requested to get printed, a corresponding raw data printing routine is invoked, with the argument of what should next lay in stack (the offset is calculated at compile time). In case of `%x`, there are no arguments, and the unchanged string to get printed is empty and thus not allocated, so the next 32-bit value that's in the stack is the current return address, the one that's generated by the OS at EXE loading time, and actually put in stack via `call printf_hex_address` assembly instruction. The attack is apparently based on the fact that if the processing program is actually persistent in memory, and won't get swapped, this address is a writable memory location within the program's address space. Why did there "Overwritten"'s length appear, can be explained by the internal string operating routine designed so that the actual length of the string is passed into it.

Comment: I still can't get what's the address that is displayed from the printf("%x") call. I need one simple sentence that describes what's this address?

Comment: this depends on the native implementation of printf. A rough guess will be "address of code called printf", although it might be as well "address of code in printf that calls internal printing routine".

Answer (score 1):

**May be helpful for you:**
I guess you are working in windows. there no strict checks are performed.
I tried same on Linux got warning.

> int main(){
>     printf("%x");
>     printf("Overwritten%n");
>   }

Gives following warning:
  $ gcc test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:4: warning: too few arguments for format
test.c:5: warning: too few arguments for format

Answer (score 1):

This is because `printf` does not know the intention of the programmer. When it sees a format identifier in the format string it formats the appropriate argument there.

```
printf("%x");
```

expects an additional argument (normally stored in a register or on the stack). Since the programmer did not tell the compiler in this call to provide an additional argument whatever is stored where `printf` expects to find the argument at that time will be printed.

For optimization reasons compilers generally do not clear registers before calling the next function.